# from list of lists get max value with index and map index value to list of string with index

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have list of lists & list , Initial need to find from list of lists argmax value with index and map list of lists index max value with another list

Input :

```
a = np.array([[9.8894545, 2.12012004, 2.1054542],
              [3.19212970, 9.6048260, 3.63252661],
              [9.97873928, 3.10315885, 2.12607185],
              [5.13391890, 4.53636282, 9.8429458]])
#type(a) -> np.ndarray
           
b = ['abc','def','ghi']
#type(b) -> list
```

Expected Output in dataframe:

```
               column_c  
                abc 
                def 
                abc 
                ghi
```

I have tried below steps but couldn't map to another list

```
     a = np.array([[9.88945457e-01, 2.12012004e-11, 2.10545428e-02],
              [3.19212970e-03, 9.60482604e-01, 3.63252661e-02],
              [9.97873928e-01, 4.10315885e-12, 2.12607185e-03],
              [5.13391890e-07, 9.84294588e-01, 4.57048982e-02]])
     sam =np.max(a, axis=1)
     df_3 = pd.DataFrame(sam, columns = ['Column_A'])
```

Output(df_3)

```
       Column_A
       0    0.99
       1    0.96
       2    0.97
       3    0.98
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### update

if you want to index the list based on the index of the max, use:

```
a = np.array([[9.8894545, 2.12012004, 2.1054542],
              [3.19212970, 9.6048260, 3.63252661],
              [9.97873928, 3.10315885, 2.12607185],
              [5.13391890, 4.53636282, 9.8429458]])
       
b = ['abc','def','ghi']

df = pd.Series(np.array(b)[a.argmax(axis=1)])
```

output:

```
0    abc
1    def
2    abc
3    ghi
dtype: object
```

as DataFrame:

```
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'column_c': np.array(b)[a.argmax(axis=1)]})
```

output:

```
  column_c
0      abc
1      def
2      abc
3      ghi
```

##### previous answer

IIUC, use:

```
a = np.array([[9.8894545, 2.12012004, 2.1054542],
              [3.19212970, 9.6048260, 3.63252661],
              [9.97873928, 3.10315885, 2.12607185],
              [5.13391890, 4.53636282, 9.8429458]])
       
b = ['abc','def','ghi']

df = pd.DataFrame(a.max(axis=0), index=b)
```

output:

```
            0
abc  9.978739
def  9.604826
ghi  9.842946
```

Comment: @sampathnandan then the logic is unclear, you should elaborate

Comment: @sampathnandan check the update

Comment: forgive i have updated kindly check

Comment: @sampathnandan that's just a detail, you can assign to an existing DataFrame `df['X'] = pd.Series(np.array(b)[a.argmax(axis=1)])` or create a DataFrame: `pd.DataFrame({'X': np.array(b)[a.argmax(axis=1)]})`

Comment: Great Thanks @mozway for the update , i thought to convert series to_frame() & assign